# I cant upload my app to the Appstore and my bundleID is correct

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

The appstore's response when i try to upload my new build is this= "no suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'com.1234.ubicalapro' is correct.'

but then i've checked the appstore and its the same bundleId im trying to upload with the build.

what can i do?

[BundleId when i try to upload it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJekS.jpg)

[BundleId in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OROj5.jpg)

[BundleId from the AppStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MofXO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error in XCode 10.0.

On closer inspection, Apple had truncated my bundle ID.

The only way I could stop XCode from truncating my bundle ID was to ...

1. Archive the app with a new bundle ID and a new app name. I did nothing with this intermediate archive.
2. Set the app name and bundle ID back to what I originally needed
3. Archive again.

After this, no more error.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the website identifier is online, like below:

[image]

Second, check for any problem in the two frameworks:

[image]